# Is there a way to debug this sorting function?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I'm currently trying to program a poker game to train my java skills.

To determine what is the best possible hand the game (so the bots can make good decisions) I assign to each possible hand a list of integers who depends of what cards they have on their hand and what cards are on the field.
for example a player who have a straight flush with highest card a 6 will have as list [8,6,0].

in which the 8 represent the straight flush and the 6 the highest card of the flush (the last number only serve for the double pair or the full house).
A player who have a pair of 10 will have as list [1,10,0,0,12,0].

in which the three first numbers represent the pair (the 1 represent the pair and the 10 the value of the pair) and the three last numbers  represent the highest card on the player hand (the 0 for the highest card and the 12 for the queen).

in the case of the straight flush there is no need for the highest card so the list only contains 3 integers.

Now, the problem is that my method to sort them work fine but sometimes it give me errors (it's a method that I use a lot so it perhaps only doesn't work 1 in 10000 ) and the program use a lots of random number so the program never execute twice the same, and  when it doesn't work there are two type of error for this same method (sometimes it's one and sometimes it's the other):

"java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" and "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" but my java skills are not good enough to tell me how to deal with it.

I tried to debug it using print but found nothing unnatural.
The system tell me that the error is coming from this method, but I'm not sure of that.

here's the code in question:

```
    public List<Score> meilleurScore(List<Score> scores) {

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        Joueur joueurGagnant;
        List<Score> scoresGagnants = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Score> toutLesScores = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Score> scoresPasEncoreFait = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Score> scoresEnCourse = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> meilleureListe = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Score> scoresAEliminer = new ArrayList<>();

        scoresPasEncoreFait.addAll(scores);
        scoresEnCourse = equilibrerLesScores(scoresEnCourse);
        while (toutLesScores.size() < scores.size()) {

            // System.out.println(meilleureListe);
            meilleureListe.clear();
            // System.out.println(toutLesScores.size());
            // System.out.println(scoresPasEncoreFait.size());
            scoresEnCourse.clear();
            // scoresAEliminer.addAll(scoresEnCourse);
            scoresEnCourse.addAll(scoresPasEncoreFait);

            for (int j = 0; j < scoresEnCourse.get(0).integers.size(); j++) {
                meilleureListe.add(0);
                meilleureListe.add(0);
                meilleureListe.add(0);
            }

            if (scoresEnCourse.get(0).integers.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < scoresEnCourse.get(0).integers.size(); i++) {

                    scoresEnCourse.removeAll(scoresAEliminer);
                    // System.out.println("3"+ scoresEnCourse);
                    scoresAEliminer.clear();

                    for (Score score : scoresEnCourse) {
                        // System.out.println(score.integers.get(i));
                        // System.out.println(meilleureListe.get(i));
                        // System.out.println("meilleur "+meilleureListe);

                        if (score.integers.get(i) < meilleureListe.get(i)) {

                            scoresAEliminer.add(score);
                        }
                        if ((score.integers.get(i) == meilleureListe.get(i)) && (!scoresGagnants.contains(score))) {
                            scoresGagnants.add(score);
                        }
                        if (score.integers.get(i) > meilleureListe.get(i)) {
                            for (Score score2 : scoresEnCourse) {
                                {
                                    if (score == score2) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    if ((score.integers.get(i) > score2.integers.get(i))
                                            && (!scoresAEliminer.contains(score2))) {
                                        scoresAEliminer.add(score2);
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            scoresGagnants.clear();
                            scoresGagnants.add(score);
                            meilleureListe = score.integers;

                        }
                        if (scoresEnCourse.size() == 1) {
                            /* System.out.println("size==1 "+scoresEnCourse); */
                            toutLesScores.addAll(scoresEnCourse);
                            scoresPasEncoreFait.removeAll(scoresEnCourse);
                            scoresAEliminer.addAll(scoresEnCourse);

                        }

                    }

                }
                /* System.out.println("else "+scoresGagnants); */
                toutLesScores.addAll(scoresGagnants);
                scoresPasEncoreFait.removeAll(scoresGagnants);
                scoresAEliminer.addAll(scoresEnCourse);

            }

        }

        return toutLesScores;
    }
```

this method use "equilibrerLesScores" which is:

```
public List<Score> equilibrerLesScores(List<Score> scores){
    int x=0;
    for (Score score : scores){
        if (score.integers.size()>x){
            x=score.integers.size();
        }
    }
    for (Score score : scores){
        while (score.integers.size()<x){
            score.integers.add(0);
        }
    }
    return scores;
}
```

In my code a Score is defined by:

```
public Score(Carte carte1, Carte carte2, List<Integer> integers){
        this.carte1=carte1;
        this.carte2=carte2;
        this.integers=integers;
        
    }
```

(and a Carte is a card )

here are the 2 errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at Table.meilleurScore(Table.java:596)
    at Table.trouverLeRangDeCetteMain(Table.java:656)
    at Table.chanceDeGagnerPlusTard(Table.java:1025)
    at Table.caractereDevin(Table.java:806)
    at Table.faireLesMises(Table.java:688)
    at Main.main(Main.java:60)
```

and

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Table.meilleurScore(Table.java:582)
    at Table.trouverLeRangDeCetteMain(Table.java:656)
    at Table.chanceDeGagnerPlusTard(Table.java:997)
    at Table.caractereDevin(Table.java:806)
    at Table.faireLesMises(Table.java:688)
    at Main.main(Main.java:53)
```

(the index and size are not always 0)
the line 596 is:

```
for (Score score : scoresEnCourse){
```

and the line 582 is:

```
for (int i=0;i<scoresEnCourse.get(0).integers.size();i++){
```

If needed I can show other parts of my code.

Thank you for reading my problem and sorry for my English.

Comment: Within the loop, you have a `scoresEnCourse.clear();`.  If that executes, then it will cause the exceptions that you're seeing.  Maybe replace that statement by adding to `scoresAEliminer`.

Comment: i changed it  and it's still show me errors

Comment: Thanks for changing it - Basically, whenever you are iterating over a list, avoid changing the elements of that list within the loop.   Also paste the updated code so we can see the current state.  It would help a lot to format it correctly, properly indented - that should be a simple keystroke in your IDE (eg on eclipse on windows, it's just Ctrl-Shift-F).

Comment: I edited it on the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should think for a comparatorFunction on your "list of hands", then you have hands.. (num players) and use the Comparable interface between "hands" and sort the "list of hands". the last or first will be the winner depending on how you user the Comparable for the sort function (compare). if i understood the objective of your program that is to determine winner and losers.

a "hand" is the collection of cards... each  hand have 5 cards to check what the player has on hand.. (from nothing to pair , pairs , full , sequence , flush).

a hand must be Comparable to another hand. and that is it.

cya.

Comment: Each hand has a score, that is the view...  the score will be the combination of the cards. i guess what is complicated in the poker game is the score function. since also depend on each suit.